# Игра "сифа".  Откуда название?

Tags: этимология

Вспомнил тут про игру "сифу" и с детских пор мучивший вопрос, а что изначально значило слово "сифа"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У нас это тоже называлось салочки, но одним из альтернативных названий было "сифак". Это не сифилис, но сифилитик. 
Но поскольку играли в возрасте в основном до 4-5 лет, то вряд ли понимали смысл названия.

Answer (score 2):

В 79-80 на переменах кидались тряпкой, которой вытирают доску в школе. Тот в кого попадали, становился грязным или пятнистым и потому звался "сифилитиком" или "сифиличкой". За пару лет название сократилось, через сифак до сифы, так же звали и грязную тряпку. Сестра (пошла в школу в 1983), узнала слово сифа в первом классе, но уже не ведала о его происхождении. Запретил ей при родителях дома произносить, бо сильно ругательным считал.

Answer (score 0):

А что за игра???

А, салки...
Вроде бы этот вопрос - о названиях этой игры и их происхождении - на Лингве не так давно обсасывался. Если интересно, могу поискать, хотя это и без меня можно...

Там из версий, кажется, была только одна насчет сифилиса, но крайне сомнительно...

Comment: Ну почему же сомнительно? У нас в школе, кажется, именно так и расшифровывали. 

Игра в том, что берется грязная тряпка, которой с доски вытирают, и кидается кому-нибудь. Тот должен быстро ее кому-нибудь другому кинуть. У кого тряпка - тот и "сифа". После такой игры у всех школьная форма грязная от мела.

Comment: Про тряпку - это уже некая вариация...
Впрочем, суть не в этом... Какая связь-то с венерическим заболеванием?

Comment: Грязь  передают  как  заразу.  Интересно,  где  в  такую  играют ?

Comment: В школе играли, было дело. Но о названии никто не задумывался. Просто было понятно, что от летящей тряпки надо увернуться, а если досталась, то поскорее избавиться.

Answer (score -1):

Место происхождение этой игры 1.Сифак 2. Сифа, респ.Башкортостан г. Кумертау, примерно 1987-88год. Весна, оттаил мусор выброшенный из окон дома и полиэтиленовый мешочек с тухлой рыбой, который я ловко пнув ногой пропал в мальчика по кличке "пу...к" а друг Ильдар крикнул Сифа! и понеслось... Перед этим мы с другом обсуждали передачу по ТВ о сифилисе печени которую я посмотрел перед тем как выйти во двор. Прототипом этой игры была "Тухляш"но согласитесь она не на столько азартна )